# Import the login theme from 11.10 to 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, login-screen, customization

How do I import the default log in theme from ubuntu 11.10 to ubuntu 11.04? I want to do this due to low functionality of 11.10, but the looks still attract me. If there is anyway to do that, I'd like to know it.
If there isn't any way, how can I customize edit and play with the settings of the log in screen? ( I mean with to edit the values in it.)

Installing lightdm does not help, many problems come from doing that, maybe in a wrong way, I've tried one guide [here].

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the terminal:
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:lightdm-team/ppa`
`sudo apt-get install lightdm lightdm-greeter-example-gtk`
You will be presented with the option of having lightdm as your default login screen or being able to switch between the two, it is your choice. See more information [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now the log in is seriously messed up. Loads low graphics login interface and no lightdm (11.10). I've followed the steps correctly. Plus it says that it couldn't find lightdm-greeter-example-gtk.

Comment: Hmmm... what do you mean by low graphics?